# Primal-dual problems of LP's

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems, operations-research

Consider the primal linear program

\begin{align}
\operatorname{min} c^T &x \\
A&x\leq b \\
&x \geq 0
\end{align}

In the dual problem, we associate each constraint $i$ with dual variable $y_i \leq 0$ and each variable $j$ with constraint $a_j^T y \leq c_j$. Therefore, the dual is

\begin{align}
\operatorname{max} b^T &y \\
A^T&y\leq c \\
&y \leq 0
\end{align}

Now if the primal is a maximization problem the memorization rule is a little different.

\begin{align}
\operatorname{max} c^T &x\\
A&x\leq b \\
&x \geq 0
\end{align}

has the dual

\begin{align}
\operatorname{min} b^T &y\\
A^T&y\geq c \\
&y \geq 0
\end{align}

I didn't want to memorize the rule for the primal max case, so I thought I could just transform the maximization problem to minimization problem and follow the steps from there.

\begin{align}
\operatorname{max} c^T &x \to - \operatorname{min} -c^T x\\
A&x\leq b \\
&x \geq 0
\end{align}

Which has the dual

\begin{align}
- \operatorname{max} b^T &y \\
A^T&y\leq -c \\
&y \leq 0
\end{align}

Now if I change the objective and multiply each row with $-1$, I get
\begin{align}
\operatorname{min} -b^T &y \\
-A^T&y\geq c \\
-&y \geq 0
\end{align}

I cannot reason that this is equivalent to $\operatorname{min}\{ b^T y \,|\, A^T y \geq c, y \geq 0\}$. Did I miss something?

Comment: Observe that $\max c^{\top}x=-\min -c^{\top}x$

Comment: @MarcelloSammarra, good point, but I'm still stuck... I feel like I'm missing something pretty simple.

Comment: That's indeed equivalent! Substitute y by. _y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are asking why
\begin{align}
\operatorname{min} -b^T &y \\
-A^T&y\geq c \\
-&y \geq 0
\end{align}

is equivalent to
\begin{align}
\operatorname{min} b^T &y\\
A^T&y\geq c \\
&y \geq 0 \;?
\end{align}

This can be seen by substituting $y$ with $-y$.

To make it more explicit:

As an intermediate step we can write down
\begin{align}
\operatorname{min} b^T &(-y) \\
 A^T&(-y)\geq c \\
&(-y) \geq 0.
\end{align}

This is equivalent to the first system by linearity,
and then if you replace $y$ with $(-y)$, you can see that it is equivalent to the second system.